# AngularJS ng-repeat not showing data in table

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have a problem with output from MySQL

**getCustomers.php** is

```
$query="select distinct c.ancestry, c.trusted from members c order by c.id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr[] = json_encode($row);
}
}

# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);
// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

and **controler** code:

```
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.list = data;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 100; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
});
$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
};
$scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() { 
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
};
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
});
```

Problem is that i get from MySQL this format (e.g.):

```
["{\"ancestry\":\"12865794218\",\"trusted\":\"128\"}"]
```

but expectable is:

```
[{"ancestry":"1286794218","trusted":"126"}]
```

so, if I write constants in data it works perfectly fine

```
$scope.list = [{"ancestry":"1286794218","trusted":"126"}];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the " \ " are correct.  the javascript show an error when you catch the array?

Comment: check this answer to clarify the backslash.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314758/8303694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're double-encoding your response. The backslashes are there because the second application of `json_encode` escapes the double quotes in the output of the first one. Remove the `json_encode` from inside your while loop.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;                        // don't encode here
    }
}
```

Then just encode it once afterward (as you already are.)

```
$json_response = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
and have another question....
How can i use non-standard symbols (ščžážý) in MySQL?... While with these symbols also not working.

Comment: This could be the subject to a separate question. I think you need to set a UTF-8 collation to your database and apply the same on your connection from the PHP script to the database. Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968438/mysql-utf8-collation-data-with-accents-not-displayed-properly-when-php-fetched

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your php code, so that the server responds with a JSON content type.

There is also a duplicate `json_encode` in your code, inside your `while` loop so you're doing duplicate json encoding, hence the unexpected output

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse() on your response. [JSON.parse docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)